# livecharts multiple series casting error

Tags: series, livecharts

I've got some problems using LiveCharts.
I'm going to add realtime data to a serie collection.

This is my Xaml:

```
    <lvc:CartesianChart DisableAnimations="True"
                                            Hoverable="False" 
                                            DataTooltip="{x:Null}"
                                            Series="{Binding Series}" 
                                            Zoom="Xy"
                                            Width="1300"
                                            />
```

.
I've created a Serie property:

```
private SeriesCollection series;
public SeriesCollection Series
{
    get { return series; }
    set { SetProperty(ref series, value, "Series"); }
}
```

initialized it in the constructor:

```
Series = new SeriesCollection();
Series.Add(new GLineSeries()
{
  Name = debugChannelSelected.Name.Replace(' ', '_'),
  Title = debugChannelSelected.Name,
  Stroke = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(debugChannelSelected.Color),
                                    Values = new GearedValues<double>(),
                                    Fill = Brushes.Transparent,
                                    PointGeometry = null
});
}
```

the debugChannelSelected is received by Messenger.

Every 100ms I'm going to add a new double to my serie collection:

```
for (var j = 0; j < SelectedChannels.Count(); j++)
{
if (SelectedChannels[j] != null)
{
    var serie =
        Series.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Title.Equals(SelectedChannels[j]));

    for (var i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
    {
        var dbt = Convert.ToDouble(rnd.Next(-1000, 10000));
        if (serie != null)
        {
            dbtValues[i] = dbt;
            serie.Values.Add(dbt);
            if (IsContinuousAcquisition && serie.Values.Count > 1000)
            {
                serie.Values.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }

    var dbtGear = dbtValues.AsGearedValues();
    serie.Values.AddRange(dbtValues);
}
else
    break;
}
```

but I'm getting a cast error in serie.Values.AddRange(dbtValues); 
.
Have you got any suggestion on how to resolve it?

Tia.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the Series.Add method as follow:

```
                    Series.Add(new GLineSeries()
                    {
                        Name = debugChannelSelected.Name.Replace(' ', '_'),
                        Title = debugChannelSelected.Name,
                        Stroke = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(debugChannelSelected.Color),
                        Values = new ChartValues<ObservableValue>(),
                        Fill = Brushes.Transparent,
                        PointGeometry = null
                    });
```

now I'm able to use AddRange.